# openlayers 4.4 : change color and symbols of wms source

Tags: javascript, openlayers

here is a wms source (mapserver) which I would like to change the color and symbols. How to do please ?

```
var installationsClasseesSourceWms =   new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'carte geol',
        visible: false,
        //opacity: 0.0,
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://mapsrefrec.brgm.fr/wxs/georisques/georisques_services?',
          params: {LAYERS: 'INSTALLATIONS_CLASSEES_SIMPLIFIE_GE', TILED: true,  FORMAT: 'image/png'},
          extent: [40428,1600797,1216896,2698833.8],
          resolutions: [1056.633663,528.3168317,264.1584158,132.0792079,66.03960396,26.41584158, 13.229166668, 6.614583334, 2.645833334],
        projection:"EPSG:4326",
                 transitionEffect: 'resize',
                 //isBaseLayer:true,
                 reproject: true,
                 //opacity: 0.0
        }),
          });
map.addLayer(installationsClasseesSourceWms);
```

Comment: If I understood you well you cannot do it, tiles and symbols from a Web Map Source are rendered images. You will need to work with an open source like Open Street Map and build it in your own server as you like. As an alternative you can use private solutions like MapBox with OL.

Comment: Hi
that's what I thought too, but since then I've learned about the sld (style layer descriptor) that I can not apply here.
https://mapserver.org/fr/ogc/sld.html

Comment: If it is SLD_BODY you want to use take a look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/175057/8673 or this https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/278900/8673